# Google oauth by adding html button, looks different in IE

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-plus, google-oauth, google-signin

I am using Oauth 2.0 for google sign in. For that, I am using html button for sign in as per https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/add-button . When I am checking this in chrome/firefox/safari it comes with red button with white text(Since I am using default theme -dark). But IE it appears as blue button with only 'g' not as 'g+'.

Browser Detail:
IE-11 on windows 8.1 - 64bit

Answer (score 0):

This is [Google testing different buttons](http://www.theverge.com/2014/4/29/5665516/sign-in-with-google-button-could-send-google-plus-to-oblivion) on a subset of visitors. Most of your users will never see the blue button. There is unlikely anything you can do about it.